# Gstreamer- MJPEG- RTSP streaming from Raspberry pi to windows

Tags: windows, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp, raspberry-pi2

I want to create a pipeline to stream a rtsp stream from my raspberry pi to Windows. I have created the following pipeline, but facing some errors when i try to get it on window side. My pipeline is as below.

*Server Side (Rpi board)*

```
gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | gst-launch fdsrc ! decodebin2 name=dec ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! jpegenc ! queue ! avimux name=mux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.1.30 port=5000 |./test-launch "( tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.30 port=5000 ! jpegdec ! rtpjpegpay name=pay0 pt=96 )"
```

*Client side (Windows)*

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.30:8554/test !application/x-rtp , payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false text-overlay=false
```

I am facing following errors [image]
Please provide appropriate solution if any, thanks in advance.